# How many tasks are created when reading parquet data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading different datasets as below

```
val df1 = spark.read.load('loc1')
val df2 = spark.read.load('loc2')
```

The number of partitions created were,

df1.rdd.getNumPartitions => 5000

df2.rdd.getNumPartitions => 334

I understand that this is based on the properties of the data.
But for both the jobs the number of tasks created was 400. Job 0 & 2 below :

[image]

**Where is this constant of 400 coming from?**

This is the configuration used to spawn the spark shell:

spark-shell-2.4.3 --driver-memory 20G --executor-memory 20G --num-executors 200 --executor-cores 2 --name spark_shell --queue default --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2G

Comment: DataFrameReader.load() seems to create as many tasks as the number of executor cores irrespective of the number of partitions being created.

Comment: Couldn't find any defaults or info explaining this in spark docs though - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#load-java.lang.String-